# When extending Collator, what should be used as the hashcode value?

Tags: java, hashcode, collation

`Collator` is an abstract class that has `hashcode()` as an abstract method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#hashCode()

My implementation of `Collator` has no internal state or constructor parameters.  What would be a good implementation of `hashcode()`?  Just pick a number?

Comment: Do you want to consider all of your `Collator` instances equal? If yes, pick a fixed number (like zero). If not, use `System.identityHashCode()`.

Comment: Note, however, that you should either also override [`Collator.equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/text/Collator.java#Collator.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), or implement `hashCode` to be consistent with that.